# Problems with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't solve a problem:

I use class ActionBarActivity, but got an error so I added `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+` in Dependences. However, I then get the next problem:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0-rc1
```

I tried to fix it by adding  `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+` but have error with `Theme.AppCompat` :

```
: 1284-1284/ua.viperhit.contextmenu E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: ua.viperhit.contextmenu, PID: 1284 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ua.viperhit.contextmenu/ua.viperhit.contextmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

On Virt. The test device shows the message "Unfortunately, Context Menu has stopped".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because, in `appcompat-v7` project, the `AndroidManifest.xml` declare `uses-sdk minSdkVersion` to 19 while your project set to 15 which is inappropriate. 
You can try set your project value greater-or-equals than value declared in `appcompat-v7`. For example, 19 in both projects.

Comment: specify the theme `android:theme="Theme.AppCompat"`

Comment: Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.AppCompat'.

Comment: It is not correct. com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+ is resolved with com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.
It requires minSdk=L. It causes the error with the minSdk.